# Overriding Styles in Material UI in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a problem overriding the styles in my theme in Material UI in React.
I wanted to customize the `border` of `columnsContainer` but it isn't working. only the `root` is working well.

[Check Here for Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-407kk?file=/theme/overrides/MuiDataGrid.js)

[image][image]

**MuiDataGrid.js**

```
export default {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    border: `1px solid green`,
    "& .columnsContainer": {
      borderBottom: `1px solid 'blue' !important`
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell. Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-407kk?file=/theme/overrides/MuiDataGrid.js. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the correct syntax. The changes compared to your code sandbox are:

1. Replace `.columnsContainer` with `.MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer`
2. Correct the borderBottom syntax to be `1px solid blue` instead of `1px solid 'blue' !important`.

```
export default {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    border: `1px solid green`,
    "& .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer": {
      borderBottom: `1px solid blue`
    }
  }
};
```

[image: Edit DataGrid columnsContainer override]